# RxJava async cache: proper way to dispose replay().autoConnect() Observable

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

I have to provide a short–lived cache for the result of the observable.

Looking at the options and I see following:

1. cache `replay(1).refCount()` and when data is ready, cache the actual value.
   Cache retrieval would check actual data and do `Observable.just` or return
   pending Observable or initiate fresh request.
2. cache `replay(1).autoConnect(1)` and always return that

latter seems more straight forward, but it has one caveat, how to correctly dispose observable when cache has to be invalidated.

There is a signature:

`public Observable<T> autoConnect(int numberOfSubscribers, Consumer<? super Disposable> connection)`

but hard to tell how I can track outstanding subscriptions and whether or not dispose will be graceful.

former will take care of resource deallocation, but you have to produce more complicated logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not `.cache()`?

```
public class CachedObservable<K,V> {
  private Function<K, Observable<V>> actual;
  private CachedObservable(Function<K, Observable<V>> actual){this.actual=actual;}
  private final Map<K, Observable<V>> cacheMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public Observable<V> get(K key) {
    return cacheMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> this.actual.call(k).cache());
  }
  public void invalidate(K key){cacheMap.remove(key);}
}
```

Comment: cache operator do not emit until sequence is complete. Also I think you have the same problem, you have to safely dispose it knowing # of active subscriptions.

Comment: Cache emits them as they come - see the [marble diagram](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#cache()), but it will subscribe to the source observable immediately, and will not unsubscribe when you have 0 subscribers, so is not good fit for non-1-sized Observables. But you *can* just leave it get garbage collected.

Comment: I tested latest 1.x, 1.2.7, this is what I see: looks like cache start emitting items immediately, this is not a problem anymore. I can supply size hint, still cannot unsubscribe from upstream, so not suitable at all for infinite source. It does garbage collect correctly, it does supports concurrent or sparse subscriptions, it pretty much covers my needs